# Debugging of dsbulk dse

Tags: cassandra, dse

I have downloaded datastax/dsbulk from https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk
Now I want to execute dsbulk count query from commandline and want it to hit the code that I have downloaded.
I am a newbie in debugging, I have dse cassandra installed and also IntelliJ that opens up the github downloaded project.

Please push me in the right direction or some refernce to attain such a scenario.

Comment: can you explain in more details what do you want to achieve? You want to debug DSBulk?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes, I want to debug the DSE code for DSBulk.

I had a similar working debug environment for nodetool. I used to exeucte nodetool status from commandline and it would stop at my breakpoint in Apache Cassandra's nodetool's appropriate file and then I got to understand the working of nodetool.

I need to make a similar environment for dsbulk

Comment: Please add more details about your configuration of debug environment, this question itself could be valuable information.